# overflow:hidden on iOS not working

Tags: css, overflow

http://www.andrewsmorris.co.uk/blog/

I have a sidebar that slides out when you click the button on the left, the problem however, is that on iOS I get horizontal scroll bars on the page when I click it.
Which I don't when I click it on a desktop browser, because it adds a class with overflow:hidden to the body class.

In theory this should prevent the same unwanted horizontal scrolling on the iPhone too, but it doesn't for reasons i cannot work out.

I could apply overflow-x:hidden to the html element, but that seems to jump the page to the top regardless of where you are, which is unwanted behaviour.

Comment: Hit the same quirk. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I'm afraid not, no.

If you're making a similar type of menu for mobile I'd recommend just having it position:fixed and have it slide over over the content.

Hell, even facebook can't figure this quirk out, their mobile side has horizontal scrollbars when the menu is open.

Comment: Thanks, andy. Appreciate the reply.

Comment: Do you have link for that page?

Also Check Jquery Mobile slide to Menu.


trying setting height and width to 100% (body and html)

if you have scrolling content use -webkit-overflow-scrolling :touch

are you using webkit transition to slide ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply overflow:hidden; and position:relative; to both  and  and they also can't be display:table, display:block works. Specifying the height and width may help as well.

Comment: It's a bit unclear where to add the `position: relative/absolute`. But after I added it, the flex-container was displayed properly and the overflow was working as expected. Would you please add an example?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know a solution that will enable you to use overflow: hidden; based on the information you are giving. I can however advise you to use iScroll for mobile scrolling!

Take a look at it on [cubiq's website](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4)